# Calkin algebra of direct sum and direct sum of calkin algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Calkin algebra is the quotient algebra of bounded linear operator module compact operator on Hilbert space. bounded operator on direct sum of Hilbert space is contained in the direct sum of bounded operator, and compact operator on direct sum of Hilbert space is contained in the direct sum of compact operator, so what about the Calkin algebra?

Comment: Doesn't spectral decomposition give you almost immediately that the two are the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what dose it mean, I'm a beginner,  would you explain it more specificly ？

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are asking if 
$$
\bigoplus_j A_j/\bigoplus_j J_j \simeq \bigoplus A_j/J_j. 
$$
Let $\gamma:\bigoplus_j A_j/\bigoplus_j J_j \to \bigoplus A_j/J_j$ be given by 
$$
\gamma(\bigoplus_j a_j+\bigoplus_jJ_j)=\bigoplus_ja_j+J_j. 
$$
This is well-defined: if $\bigoplus (a_j'-a_j)\in\bigoplus_j J_j$, then $a_j'-a_j\in J_j$ for all $j$. It is trivial to check that is a $*$-homomorphism. It is one-to-one: if $\bigoplus_ja_j+J_j=\bigoplus_j J_j$, then $a_j\in J_j$ for all $j$, so $\bigoplus_j a_j\in \bigoplus_j J_j$. And onto: given $\bigoplus_j a_j+J_j$, this is clearly $\gamma(\bigoplus_j a_j+\bigoplus_j J_j)$.

So $\gamma$ is a $*$-isomorphism.

Comment: that's not I'm asking for. I'm not good at English.  I mean the calkin algebra of infinite direct sum of Hlibert space and the algebra formed by infinite direct sum of calkin algebra of each Hilber space.

Comment: The answer to that is obviously no. The Calkin algebra is simple, and a direct sum has lots of ideals.

Comment: so they are not the same, and the left is very larger than the right？

Comment: Not sure what "left" or "right" is. And I'm not sure what "larger" would be here.  There is no natural way that I can see for  $\bigoplus B(H_j)/K(H_j)$ to be seen as a subalgebra of $B(\bigoplus H_j)/K(\bigoplus H_j)$.